# DataGridView.DataSource stopped triggering DataSourceChanged event

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In my code I used to do the following in the RowEnter event of another DataGridView:

```
dgv.DataSource = SomeFunctionReturningDataTable(ID)
```

The function looks like this:

```
Function SomeFunctionReturningDataTable(ByVal ID As String) As DataTable

If ds.Tables.Contains("Detail") Then
    ds.Tables("Detail").Clear()
End If

'SQL query with DataAdapter using ID

Return ds.Tables("Detail")

End Function
```

The second datagridview (`dgv`) shows more detailed information about the currently selected record in the other datagridview.

The function is correctly returning a datatable with correct data.

I then do some formating in the datagridview for the new data in the `DataSourceChanged` event:

```
Private Sub dgv_DataSourceChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgv.DataSourceChanged
    FormatDGV(dgv)
End Sub
```

However, the DataSourceChanged event has stopped triggering since a specific version. In the previous version this works.

However, I've been using this for numerous releases and it's always worked up until now and the code for this is exactly the same in both versions.

In the working version I've verified that the DataSourceChanged event is definitely firing after this line is completed `dgv.DataSource = SomeFunctionReturningDataTable(ID)`.

The same line, with the same function, running in the new version is not triggering the event.

What could possibly have happened to break this?

Comment: Try setting the DGV's DataSource to `null` (`Nothing`) before setting a new one.

Comment: This does the trick to get it working, thanks. I'm confused as it why it's stopped working in the first place, since it's worked for multiple versions before...

Comment: `DataSourceChanged` event is not fired, because you really are not changing datasource. You just clear the data and return the same table - you are setting datasource to the same table (same object instance) over and over. There is a check in the `DataSource` property and if the new value is the same as the old one, nothing is happening. I suspect, that in the version which worked, you did not clear the table, but deleted it and created a new one. So you had new table (new datasource) every time.

Comment: Thanks Stano, that logically makes sense. However, the code which populates and sets DataSource was exactly the same between the two versions. I debugged and stepped through both to make sure.